# jQuery Loop through all with Placeholder and set focus

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with the Material Design label animation collapsing on inputs with a dynamic value or placeholder. I want to loop through all input with a placeholder attribute on the page on page load and set the focus on that field to trigger that animation. After the loop I want to put focus on the first input.

I tried to add a class of "labeled" to all inputs with a placeholeder and a label and put the following in Document Ready, but it didn't work.

```
$('.labeled').focus();
$('input:first').focus();
```

Comment: Use `always-float-label="true"` attribute on the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[placeholder]').each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).focus();
    });
    $('input]:first').focus();
});
```

you need to run an each because then you can add a trigger a focus event each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

That's it ! https://jsfiddle.net/3ckqo1ov/3/

The problem is that you'll focus each input, one after the other, and only the last one will be "really" focus at the end of the loop.
But this is not a problem if you are doing stuff on the `onFocus` event :)